# How to find out if a symbolic link points to a missing directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, symlink

I have a symbolic link to a directory that does not exist:

```
~/ramdisk -> /dev/shm/mydir
```

When running my Python code, I get the error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/ramdisk'

How can I avoid this error, detecting beforehand the fact the directory is missing?

The only method I found is `symlink()`, which creates a symbolic link.

Comment: Use `pathlib.Path.exists`.  Or better still `pathlib.Path.is_dir`.  See https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#methods.

Comment: (or the plain `os.path.exists` / `os.path.isdir`, though I do prefer the pathlib way)

Comment: Python filenames don't know about the special meaning of the `~` character.  Use `os.path.expanduser()`.

Comment: check all functions in [os.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) - it is good to know its names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of symlinks is that `~/ramdisk` is treated essentially the same as `/dev/shm/mydir` would be unless you are doing symlink specific operations.

```
import os
os.path.exists('~/ramdisk')
# or, as suggested by Stephen:
from pathlib import Path
Path('~/ramdisk').is_dir()
```

would all be the same as if you used checked `/dev/shm/mydir` instead.